# why is my postgres database so big?

Tags: postgresql

i'm running PostgreSQL 9.4.6 and I have a database that's 78GB found by running

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size('<db name>')) As fulldbsize;
```

In order to track down why my database is so big I've tried the following:-

```
SELECT relname as "Table",      
       pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size(relid)) As "Size",
       pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size(relid) - pg_relation_size(relid)) as "External Size" 
FROM pg_catalog.pg_statio_user_tables 
ORDER BY pg_total_relation_size(relid) DESC;
```

But when adding up the resulting tables I get to about 15GB.

What's using my up the space in my database?  What further commands can I run?

Comment: Your second query only takes tables into account, but not indexes. And it doesn't include tables (and indexes) owned by other users, toast tables and system tables (although system tables are unlikely to need 63GB)

Answer (score 1):

you can also get information about all objects and their respective sizes

```
 SELECT
 relname AS objectname,
 relkind AS objecttype,
 reltuples AS "#entries", pg_size_pretty(relpages::bigint*8*1024) AS size
 FROM pg_class
 WHERE relpages >= 8
 ORDER BY relpages DESC;
```

This should detail:

- objectname – The name of the object
- objecttype – r for the table, i for an index, t for toast data, ...
- entries – The estimated number of entries in the object (e.g. rows)
- size – The size of the object

Comment: I'm late to the game, but what if the posgresql disk space used is not accounted for by the output in your command above. On my system, your command accounts for about 300G of space, but the disk space consumed is more like 480G.

Answer (score 1):

This will list all objects an their size:

```
SELECT relname, pg_total_relation_size(oid)
FROM pg_class
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

That should help you account for the database size.